# Changing the Chart Properties with VBA Crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an activeX button on my dashboard that updates one of my charts. Chart is fed by a power query table and depending on the data this table increases or decreases in column number. So the code block below sets the properties of a chart where column number is dynamic.

```
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Hesap_Duruşlar2").Range("Stoppage_Model_Filter[#All]")

Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chrt_Stoppage_Model_Time").Activate
With Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chrt_Stoppage_Model_Time").Chart
    For i1 = 1 To .FullSeriesCollection.Count
        If i1 <> .FullSeriesCollection.Count Then
                .FullSeriesCollection(i1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
                .FullSeriesCollection(i1).AxisGroup = 1
        Else
            .FullSeriesCollection(i1).ChartType = xlLine
            .FullSeriesCollection(i1).AxisGroup = 1
        End If
    Next i1
End With
```

After running the code excel crashes without giving me any error messages. If I go through it line by line, it goes through the first 4 series just fine but then crashes at the fifth, again without giving an error message.

So what is going on here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. When you step through the code, which line is the last one that executes without crashing?

Comment: The code works fine for me. There is no need to activate your chart first, it's probably better not to. Could you use a Form button, or even a shape with an associated macro instead of an ActiveX button? ActiveX can sometimes cause weird things to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in my environment and it runs ok.
If you have the option to restart your computer, please try, to ensure there are no pending Windows Updates. Also, run Office Repair if you have that option. Finally, you may find more error information if you go to your Windows Event Viewer.